# How to read Activity name from log cat in android?

Tags: android

How we can Read Activity name from `logcat` in Android?
I used some code but didn't get Activity name which I launched.

```
String baseCommand = "logcat -d time";
baseCommand += " ActivityManager:I "; // Info for my app
baseCommand += " *:S "; // Silence others
try
{
    Process logReaderProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(baseCommand);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logReaderProcess.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        Log.e("This is Camera open log",""+log);
        log.append(line); // here readLine() returns null
    }
}
catch (IOException e1)
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can someone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same command **works for getting Activity Manager info from adb logcat** now from that `you can extract activity name from the tag "Activity Manager" which last appeared.`